# react always redirect to homepage

Tags: reactjs, redirect, nginx

First of all I'm new to react, so i'm still learning about it.

I got this problem with react if I make a hyperlink from another domain/site to react app on localhost, eg http://localhost:8089/foo/bar. it show the correct page directly but if I make a hyperlink from another domain/site to a public domain with https protocol eg https://example.com/foo/baz it always redirected to homepage page (https://example.com/)

is there anything I can do to make it go straight to https://example.com/foo/baz. I run react on nginx web server with this redirection setting it went well for php, django etc but won't run with react.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    root /home/[path to dist folder]/web/app/dist;
    index index.html index.htm;

}
```

FYI the react app is build with webpack thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've manage to put the right config for the file.

it should be like this

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        ...
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    ...

}
```

thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0):

I things the probleme is :

```
"return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;"
```

You should maybe replace it :

```
"return 301 https://$server_name/$request_uri;"
```

Comment: Can i have the full configuration please ?